# Register all view models as named services in Autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I'd like to register all view models under the current executing assembly and resolve them by their name.

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly())
    .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("ViewModel"))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

I looked at how resolution by name works in `Autofac`:

```
builder.RegisterType<XViewModel>().Named<IXViewModel>("XViewModel");

var r = container.ResolveNamed<IXViewModel>("XViewModel");
```

but, to me it looked like named registrations would have to be done manually for each service.

Is there a way to make this process simpler so I can use a single line to register all assembly types as named services (each service would be resolved by the name of the view model)?

Comment: In my project, I think I was simply able to call Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().AsImplementedInterfaces() and it would automatically register all the types in the project to their interfaces. Is there any reason you only want to register your view models?

Comment: @CiaranGallagher Since I'm new to DI, I can't tell you why, but if I wanted to use some types as singleton, wouldn't your recommendation fail? Also, I'm having trouble with the resolution part - not the registration part. Previously, I was assigning view models to views via reflection / Activator.CreateInstance based on the name of the view. Now, idk how to do that with Autofac.

Comment: You might want to explain what you're trying to solve on a larger level. In general with DI you don't call container.Resolve - that's service location, not DI. You may be making your life harder than it needs to be.